# when using exporting(highchart) in angular 7 got the the error

Tags: highcharts, angular7

using exporting(highchart) getting below error:
ERROR in src/app/desktop/module/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts(24,1): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import("C:/website/UI_Dashboard/node_modules/highchart
s/modules/exporting.src")' has no compatible call signatures.

in the module:

```
import {ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES} from 'angular-highcharts';
import * as more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src';
import * as highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting.src';
import * as offline from 'highcharts/modules/offline-exporting';
exporting(highcharts);
offline(highcharts);
```

what should I do for solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `import exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting.src';`?

It's the suggested way of module working as documented in the official Highcharts wrapper for Angular - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#core

You should also load all Highcharts related files as `src` or minified - mixing might cause some TS issues.

An `import` path for `src` version of Highcharts core is `'highcharts/highcharts.src'`.

Also (I'm not sure if this applies here since the code might not be complete), `highcharts-more` needs to be initialized as any other module. Usually it is loaded before other modules - initialization order is rarely important (some series types are based on optional modules) and you will get an error if the order is wrong, so it's important to test this.

Comment: Adding .src is also resulting same

Comment: @SubhabrataBanerjee Use the same version (e.g. 9.0.1) for the core and modules. Use the same extension (.src.js or .js) for the core and modules. If the error still shows create a live demo.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone encounters this problem nowadays, changing this:

```
import * as exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting.src';
```

To this:

```
import Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
```

Solved the problem for me.

I'm using Angular CLI 11.1.4 and the Highcharts npm package v9.2.2